# How to implement service discovery in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, microservices, service-discovery

Can somebody please explain how to implement service discovery with nodejs without any frameworks. only with nodejs and express.

All I can found it how to implement this with frameworks like sprint boot (which i don't want to use) on youtube.

What Steps I need to do to implement this. it very will help if example of the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

A service discovery service is a service that provides endpoints to manage URLs or IPs of other services in the same environment. It's good practice because it allows to decouple services from each other. Reason is that with a service discovery system, services do not need to store each other's URLs or IPs. These values can simple be fetched from the discovery service. URLs or IPs can then also be updated at runtime (still with a grace period of course).

A very basic service discovery service would provide endpoints to

- register a service instance,
- to unregister a service instance, and
- to lookup registered instances.

Translated to HTTP verbs:

- `POST` /service/:name
- `DELETE` /service/:name/:id
- `GET` /service/:name

This of course does not take into account,

- authentication and authorization to prevent unwanted manipulation
- health checks to make sure that all registered services are actually alive and healthy
- and how to set up storage so that the service is fast and scalable.

Though, it should give an idea on where to start. Generally i'd advise to use a proven solution like i.e. https://www.consul.io/